# How to copy commit metadata (author, date) from another commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm sure there is a way to do this in git, but my searches are coming up empty. Is there an easy way to get the message, commit author, commit date and other info from one commit and amend the second commit with this data, without copying the actual commit contents?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `-c` flag:

```
$ git commit --amend --no-edit -c <other commit hash>
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it used the long form of the option (for clarity). After looking at the `git commit --help`, I learned that there's `--reuse-message` (`-C`) and `--reedit-message` (`-c`), with the latter being the same as the former except the editor is invoked. Therefore, `--no-edit` with `-c` seems to be the same as `-C` (`--reuse-message`), so this answer is inferior to that of @Edward Grech.

Answer (score 10):

```
git commit --amend --reuse-message=<source commit hash>
```

Comment: **WARNING to unsuspecting readers:** Using `--amend` will change the existing head commit (as what the OP wanted). To create a new commit, exclude this option.